# Growing html div css design template.

Tags: php, css, ajax, html

I want all my web pages in my php application with a section between a header and footer to auto grow with ajax reloads. The footer should always be after the content that may grow up or down. How can i do this?.i expect a div based page layout with css styling that does the task Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a default behavior. You don't have to do anything explicitly. Please be more specific with what you have tried so far and any problem your facing.

Answer (score 0):

Uh.. you are looking for a div which expands automatically, between two other divs?

```
<div>Put header here</div>
<div>Put content here</div>
<div>Put footer here</div>
```

All the items should have **position:relative;** CSS property to them (Which is standard).. If you want to make sure they break on a new line, give them **display:block;**

I dont understand this question.